# Interfacing R307 to RPI without USB Serial Converter

Tags: pi-4, python-3, uart

Good day I am trying to interface the **r307 fingerprint module** in raspberry pi 4 however as what I can see every example or tutorials require **USB SERIAL CONVERTER** is it possible to interface the module without it as what I can see the pi itself has

5v, rx,tx,ground the problem is if i directly interface it to pi what will be the right thing to do
for this part
**ls -l /dev/ttyUSB***

Comment: Please write proper sentences with punctuation. It's hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

The Pi's UART is GPIO 14 (TX) and GPIO 15 (RX).

https://pinout.xyz/

Connect one ends TX to the other ends RX.  You also need to connect the grounds of both ends.

The Pi's GPIO are 3V3.  They and the Pi will expire if you connect 5V.  So make sure the voltage being received on the Pi's RX is dropped from 5V to a Pi safe 3V3.  You should be okay on the Pi TX pin as 3V3 will probably be seen as high at the other end.

The UART is accessed via `/dev/serial0`.